# Dojo ComboBox menu items grouped for use in columns

Tags: combobox, dojo, dijit.form

What I have is a select with a list of over a hundred years in a ComboBox (using dojo 1.8). Instead of scrolling through the large list I've had to make each display inline-block in a grid-looking display (which works.)

The new requirement is to instead of displaying them horizontally like this:

```
2013 2012 2011 2010
2009 2008 2007 2006
2005 2004 2003 2002
2001 2000
```

I need to display them vertically like this:

```
2013 2009 2005 2001
2012 2008 2004 2000
2011 2007 2003
2010 2006 2002
```

I'd essentially like to group the menu items of a combo box into something like every 10 items, wrapping them in another div that I could turn into columns with CSS (not using CSS3.)

I am having a bit of trouble manipulating how the menu list is rendered because it's created in the DOM after the select is initially selected.

Here's a quick HTML reference including the data dojo type:

```
<select name="year" id="year" value="1942" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/ComboBox">
    <option value="2013">2013</option>
    <option value="2012">2012</option>
    <option value="2011">2011</option>
    <option value="2010">2010</option>
    <option value="2009">2009</option>
    <option value="2008">2008</option>
    <option value="2007">2007</option>
    <option value="2006">2006</option>
    <option value="2005">2005</option>
    <option value="2004">2004</option>
    <option value="2003">2003</option>
    <option value="2002">2002</option>
    <option value="2001">2001</option>
    <option value="2000">2000</option>
    <option value="1999">1999</option>
    <option value="1998">1998</option>
    <option value="1997">1997</option>
    <option value="1996">1996</option>
    <option value="1995">1995</option>
    <option value="1994">1994</option>
    <option value="1993">1993</option>
    <option value="1992">1992</option>
    <option value="1991">1991</option>
    <option value="1990">1990</option>
    <option value="1989">1989</option>
    <option value="1988">1988</option>
    <option value="1987">1987</option>
    <option value="1986">1986</option>
    <option value="1985">1985</option>
    <option value="1984">1984</option>
    <option value="1983">1983</option>
    <option value="1982">1982</option>
    <option value="1981">1981</option>
    <option value="1980">1980</option>
    <option value="1979">1979</option>
    <option value="1978">1978</option>
    <option value="1977">1977</option>
    <option value="1976">1976</option>
    <option value="1975">1975</option>
    <option value="1974">1974</option>
    <option value="1973">1973</option>
    <option value="1972">1972</option>
    <option value="1971">1971</option>
    <option value="1970">1970</option>
    <option value="1969">1969</option>
    <option value="1968">1968</option>
    <option value="1967">1967</option>
    <option value="1966">1966</option>
    <option value="1965">1965</option>
    <option value="1964">1964</option>
    <option value="1963">1963</option>
    <option value="1962">1962</option>
    <option value="1961">1961</option>
    <option value="1960">1960</option>
    <option value="1959">1959</option>
    <option value="1958">1958</option>
    <option value="1957">1957</option>
    <option value="1956">1956</option>
    <option value="1955">1955</option>
    <option value="1954">1954</option>
    <option value="1953">1953</option>
    <option value="1952">1952</option>
    <option value="1951">1951</option>
    <option value="1950">1950</option>
    <option value="1949">1949</option>
    <option value="1948">1948</option>
    <option value="1947">1947</option>
    <option value="1946">1946</option>
    <option value="1945">1945</option>
    <option value="1944">1944</option>
    <option value="1943">1943</option>
    <option value="1942">1942</option>
    <option value="1941">1941</option>
    <option value="1940">1940</option>
    <option value="1939">1939</option>
    <option value="1938">1938</option>
    <option value="1937">1937</option>
    <option value="1936">1936</option>
    <option value="1935">1935</option>
    <option value="1934">1934</option>
    <option value="1933">1933</option>
    <option value="1932">1932</option>
    <option value="1931">1931</option>
    <option value="1930">1930</option>
    <option value="1929">1929</option>
    <option value="1928">1928</option>
    <option value="1927">1927</option>
    <option value="1926">1926</option>
    <option value="1925">1925</option>
    <option value="1924">1924</option>
    <option value="1923">1923</option>
    <option value="1922">1922</option>
    <option value="1921">1921</option>
    <option value="1920">1920</option>
    <option value="1919">1919</option>
    <option value="1918">1918</option>
    <option value="1917">1917</option>
    <option value="1916">1916</option>
    <option value="1915">1915</option>
    <option value="1914">1914</option>
    <option value="1913">1913</option>
    <option value="1912">1912</option>
    <option value="1911">1911</option>
    <option value="1910">1910</option>
    <option value="1909">1909</option>
    <option value="1908">1908</option>
    <option value="1907">1907</option>
    <option value="1906">1906</option>
    <option value="1905">1905</option>
    <option value="1904">1904</option>
    <option value="1903">1903</option>
    <option value="1902">1902</option>
    <option value="1901">1901</option>
    <option value="1900">1900</option>
</select>
```

More simply put: I'd like it to skip the first "Previous Choices" div (.dijitMenuItem) and then add a parent div, toss in 10 items, add another, toss in 10 more ... like this:

```
<div class="dijitMenuItemGroup">
    <div class="dijitReset dijitMenuItem" role="option" item="0" id="year_popup0">2013</div>
    <div class="dijitReset dijitMenuItem" role="option" item="1" id="year_popup1">2012</div>
    <div class="dijitReset dijitMenuItem" role="option" item="2" id="year_popup2">2011</div>
    <div class="dijitReset dijitMenuItem" role="option" item="3" id="year_popup3">2010</div>
    <div class="dijitReset dijitMenuItem" role="option" item="4" id="year_popup4">2009</div>
    <div class="dijitReset dijitMenuItem" role="option" item="5" id="year_popup5">2008</div>
    <div class="dijitReset dijitMenuItem" role="option" item="6" id="year_popup6">2007</div>
    <div class="dijitReset dijitMenuItem" role="option" item="7" id="year_popup7">2006</div>
    <div class="dijitReset dijitMenuItem" role="option" item="8" id="year_popup8">2005</div>
    <div class="dijitReset dijitMenuItem" role="option" item="9" id="year_popup9">2004</div>
</div>
<div class="dijitMenuItemGroup">
    <div class="dijitReset dijitMenuItem" role="option" item="10" id="year_popup10">2003</div>
    ...
</div>
...
```

Can it be done? Is there a dijit prop for something like that?

Answer (score 0):

This looks impossible to me using a dijit/form/ComboBox (but maybe I'm wrong), reason being that dijit/form/ComboBox does not support optiongroups. See https://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/10761.

I would advise you to build a custom widget using dgrid instead. If you don't know it, you can check an example of how to use it as a replacement for a drop-down select (with some flexibility added to how you render your options) here : http://dojofoundation.org/packages/dgrid/tutorials/drop_down/